# how to intercept audio from web page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-recording

What I'm trying to do is to simultaneously record a video from html5 canvas, which I managed to do, along with all the sounds being played on that page. Just to make it clear, I'm not trying to record sound from microphone, I am trying to intercept sound played on a page and record it.

The website is a browser game built with html5 browser (lime engine if it matters), and along with the video of battles it plays sounds. However it's not a single media file being player, rather multiple sounds being played, mostly several at the same time.

I'm wondering if it's possible to record all of it in a single audio file, so I can later play it simultaneously with a captured video? I did some reverse engineering of the game code and it looks like every time they need to play a sound they create an instance of Audio. Is there any kind of "master audio context" I can use and stream out audio, pretty much like captureStream of canvas, which I use to record canvas as video.

Thanks!

EDIT:
It is also likely I'm going to run that page using CEF in a background process with an offscreen buffer, so maybe that's also a way to do it using CEF.